# Regex : matches all 7 digit number except the one that starts with abc

Tags: java, regex

ex:
abc:1234567,cd:2345678,efg:3456789012

expected outcome
2345678

I tried

```
(?!abc)\d{7,7}
```

my result: 1234567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?<!abc:)\d{7}\b
(?<!\d)(?<!abc:)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ii3lQB/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary (`(?<!\d)` makes sure there is no other digit immediately to the left of the current location)
- `(?<!abc:)`  - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `abc:` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{7}` - seven digits
- `\b` - word boundary (`(?!\d)` makes sure there is no other digit immediately to the right of the current location).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/eeAiPI):

```java
String s = "abc:1234567,cd:2345678,efg:3456789012";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?<!abc:)\\d{7}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());  // => 2345678
}
```